# How to call swift function

Tags: swift

I have a function:

```
func chatAttachmentService(chatAttachmentService: QMChatAttachmentService, didChangeLoadingProgress progress: CGFloat, forChatAttachment attachment: QBChatAttachment)
```

I want to call it in my file:

```
self.chatAttachmentService(chatAttachmentService, progress, attachment)
```

I know it's crazy question, but Xcode does not show for me a hint when typing name of function and I don't know how to call it in right way...

Comment: you mean Xcode intelligence is not working? Then Quit Xcode and restart it.

Comment: Try relaunching Xcode and cleaning your build folder. Although note that first parameter name is omitted when calling a function, unless it has an explicit external parameter name.

Comment: @JigarTarsariya yea you're right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example you can do it this way:

Here is example function:

```
func testFunction(chatAttachmentService: String, didChangeLoadingProgress progress: String, forChatAttachment attachment: String) {

    //Your code
}
```

And you can call it this way:

```
testFunction("", didChangeLoadingProgress: "", forChatAttachment: "")
```